# poltergeist: apple window server permission error

Tags: phantomjs, file-permissions, poltergeist

I am using [poltergeist](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist) to execute tests, recently this has stopped working. The first spec that tries using it fails with this error:

```
phantomjs[37617] <Error>: Set a breakpoint at CGSLogError to catch errors as they are logged.
phantomjs[37617] <Error>: On-demand launch of the Window Server is allowed for root user only.
phantomjs[37617] <Warning>: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (268435459)
phantomjs[37617] <Error>: On-demand launch of the Window Server is allowed for root user only.
phantomjs[37617] <Warning>: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (268435459)
phantomjs[37617] <Error>: This user is not allowed access to the window system right now.
phantomjs[37617] <Warning>: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
phantomjs[37617] <Warning>: Invalid Connection ID 0
phantomjs[37617:3258922] Could not rendezvous with font server (error 268435459)
phantomjs[37617:3258922] XType: unable to make a connection to the font daemon!
phantomjs[37617:3258922] registering /System/Library/Fonts/*, /System/Library/Fonts/Base/*, and /Library/Fonts/* locally
```

Reinstalling phantomjs, as well as poltergeist had no effect.
Googling this brings me far away from my known rubyverse.
I am guessing this is a permissions issue, but have no clue where to start looking.

I'd greatly appreciate a pointing in the right direction.